# Integral$\int_1^\infty \log \log \left(x\right)\frac{dx}{1-x+x^2}=\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt 3}\left(\frac{5}{6}\log (2\pi)-\log \Gamma \frac{1}{6}\right)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals

UPDATED

Hi I am trying to prove the following$$
I:=\int_1^\infty \log \log \left(x\right)\frac{dx}{1-x+x^2}=\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt 3}\left(\frac{5}{6}\log (2\pi)-\log \Gamma \big(\frac{1}{6}\big)\right).
$$
I am not sure at all how to get started on this one.  This looks quite intimidating.  Something I realized was 
$$
\int_1^\infty \log \log \left(x\right)\frac{dx}{1-x+x^2}=\int_0^1 \log \log \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\frac{dx}{1-x+x^2}.
$$Thanks.

Note the Gamma function is given by 
$$
\Gamma(n)=(n-1)!,\quad \Gamma(z)=\int_0^\infty t^{z-1}e^{-t}\, dt.
$$
EDIT:  THE incorrect integral I first posted was because of a typo.  The result of it is given by (notice the denominator sign mistake I made)
$$
I_2:=\int_0^1 \log \log \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\frac{dx}{1+x+x^2}=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt 3}\log\left(\frac{\sqrt[3]{2\pi}\Gamma(2/3)}{\Gamma(1/3)}\right).
$$
as you can see the results are different, enjoy both.  Obviously, I am ONLY interested in solving I thanks.

Comment: $\displaystyle\large\ln\left(1 \over x\right) < 0$ when $\displaystyle\large x > 1$.

Comment: @integrals : Can you check the question? Changing the limits to 0..1 also does not match with the answer numerically.

Comment: -1. Why the upvotes? There are obvious problems with this question. (Not to mention the usual lack of context.)

Comment: I see Omran Kouba edited the question. Is the stated result correct now?

Comment: This is explicitly calculated in a paper of  Victor Adamchik. "A class of logarithmic integrals. Proceedings ISSAC, 1–8, 1997". It goes back to  Bierens de Haan, "Nouvelles Tables d’Intégrales Définies"  (Table 148 (5)-page 208) (1867).

Comment: @OmranKouba : Thanks for the paper. It's available [here](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~adamchik/articles/issac/issac97.ps), and the result is actually $$\frac{2\, \pi}{\sqrt{3}}\, \left(\frac{2}{3}\log{(2\, \pi)}-\frac{1}{4}\log{(3)}-\log{\Gamma{\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)}}\right)\approx -0.126321481706210$$

Comment: @gar You are right, the answer as is given corresponds to $\int_0^1\frac{\log \log(1/x)}{1-x+x^2}dx$.

Comment: @mrf it was merely a typo, i meant to write $1-x+x^2$ in denominator.  What context are you looking for?  "The usual lack of context", what does this refer to?  Thanks for your rude comment:)

Comment: @OmranKouba Yes small typo, sorry about that.  ANd sorry to everyone, I meant to have 1-x in denominator.  Sorry about that.

Comment: @gar sorry I meant to have 1-x in denominator not 1+x.  Thanks I just saw all the messages.

Comment: @gar I added what that original integral I posted is equal to.  Sorry for the typo thanks for catching it

Comment: This integral is also computed in Adamchick's paper, page 8, formula (31). http://repository.cmu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1095&context=compsci

Comment: @Leucippus Thanks a lot for this paper

Comment: @Integrals : That's okay, typos happen! Thanks to OmranKouba for pointing out the paper, we got exposed to many more interesting integrals!

Comment: @gar Yes many more interesting integrals in this paper.  Thank you my friend

Comment: @Integrals, please go to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/874431/a-closed-form-of-int-01-frac-ln-ln-left1-x-rightx2-x1-mathrm-dx/874795#874795 to see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an answer. Clear, letting $x\to 1/x$, we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
I=\int_0^1 \log(-\log x)\frac{1}{1-x+x^2}dx. 
\end{eqnarray*}
Then the rest follows from [A closed form of $\int_0^1\frac{\ln\ln\left({1}/{x}\right)}{x^2-x+1}\mathrm dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/874431/a-closed-form-of-int-01-frac-ln-ln-left1-x-rightx2-x1-mathrm-dx/874795#874795).

Comment: You're cheating Mr. xpaul! +1 ≧◠◡◠≦✌

Comment: @V-Moy, what do you mean?