# A closed form of $\int_0^1\frac{\ln\ln\left({1}/{x}\right)}{x^2-x+1}\mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, closed-form

This integral has been bugging me since yesterday:

> $$\int_0^1\frac{\ln\ln\left({1}/{x}\right)}{x^2-x+1}\mathrm dx$$

I've tried substitution $y={1}/{x}$ and $e^y={1}/{x}$, but those didn't help much. Wolfram Alpha gives me result: $-0.67172$. Could anyone here please help me to obtain the closed form of the integral preferably (**if possible**) with elementary ways (high school methods)? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Closed form via mathematica $$\frac{\pi  \left(\log \left(\frac{128}{27}\right)+8 \log (\pi )-12 \log \left(\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)\right)\right)}{3 \sqrt{3}}$$

Comment: @Brad Thanks, but how to get it? Anyway, you didn't complete [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/871037/133248).

Comment: See the paper of Victor Adamchik (freely avalable):http://repository.cmu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1095&context=compsci, More precisely Example 3.4.

Comment: Thank you so much Prof. @OmranKouba (* ˘⌣˘)◞[_]♥[_]ヽ(•‿• )

Comment: Finally I got a result which is a little bit different from the result which Brad gave.

Comment: @Anastasiya-Romanova This integral is one of _Malmsten's integrals_. You find several complete solutions for this and similar integrals in [this paper](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/257381156_Rediscovery_of_Malmsten%27s_integrals_their_evaluation_by_contour_integration_methods_and_some_related_results). Note that the unique solution which does not require the knowledge of higher analysis is perhaps that given by Malmsten in 1842, other solutions being certainly more complicated.

Comment: @OmranKouba this is updated link : https://www.researchgate.net/publication/221564534_A_Class_of_Logarithmic_Integrals

Answer (score 17, accepted):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
With $\ds{r \equiv {1 + \root{3}\ic \over 2} = \expo{\pi\ic/3}}$
\begin{align}&\color{#c00000}{
\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{\ln\pars{1/x}} \over x^{2} - x + 1}\,\dd x}
=\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{\ln\pars{1/x}} \over \pars{x - r}\pars{x - r^{*}}}\,\dd x
\\[3mm]&=\int_{0}^{1}\ln\pars{\ln\pars{1/x}}
\pars{{1 \over x - r} - {1 \over x - r^{*}}}\,{1 \over r - r^{*}}\,\dd x
\\[3mm] & =
{1 \over \Im\pars{r}}\,\Im\int_{0}^{1}
{\ln\pars{\ln\pars{1/x}} \over x - r}\,\dd x
\end{align}

> With $\ds{x \equiv \expo{-t}}$:
>   \begin{align}&\color{#c00000}{
> \int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{\ln\pars{1/x}} \over x^{2} - x + 1}\,\dd x}
> ={2\root{3} \over 3}\Im\int_{\infty}^{0}{\ln\pars{t} \over \expo{-t} - r}
> \,\pars{-\expo{-t}\,\dd t}
> \\[3mm]&=-\,{2\root{3} \over 3}\Im\bracks{{1 \over r}\int_{0}^{\infty}
> {\ln\pars{t}\expo{-t} \over 1  - \expo{-t}/r}\,\dd t}
> \\[3mm]&=-\,{2\root{3} \over 3}\Im\bracks{{1 \over r}
> \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over r^{n - 1}}\int_{0}^{\infty}
> \ln\pars{t}\expo{-nt}\,\dd t}
> \\[3mm]&=-\,{2\root{3} \over 3}\Im\lim_{\mu\ \to\ 0}\partiald{}{\mu}\bracks{
> \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}r^{-n}\int_{0}^{\infty}t^{\mu}\expo{-nt}\,\dd t}
> \\[3mm]&=-\,{2\root{3} \over 3}\Im\lim_{\mu\ \to\ 0}\partiald{}{\mu}\bracks{
> \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{r^{-n} \over n^{\mu + 1}}\Gamma\pars{\mu + 1}}
> \\[3mm]&=-\,{2\root{3} \over 3}\Im\lim_{\mu\ \to\ 0}\partiald{}{\mu}\bracks{
> \Gamma\pars{\mu + 1}{\rm Li}_{\mu + 1}\pars{r^{*}}}
> \\[3mm]&=-\,{2\root{3} \over 3}\Im\lim_{\mu\ \to\ 0}\partiald{}{\mu}\bracks{
> \Gamma\pars{\mu + 1}{\rm Li}_{\mu + 1}\pars{\expo{-\pi\ic/3}}}
> \end{align}

$\ds{{\rm Li}_{1}\pars{z} = -\ln\pars{1 - z}}$. Derivatives of the
[PolyLogarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm), respect of the order, can be evaluated from its integral representation.

Also, see [Hurwitz Zeta Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_zeta_function).

Answer (score 14):

Let $x=e^{-u}$. Then:
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_0^1\frac{\ln\ln\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}{x^2-x+1}dx&=&\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-u}\ln u}{e^{-2u}-e^{-u}+1}du
\end{eqnarray}
Let:
\begin{eqnarray}
I(a)&=&\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-u}u^a}{e^{-2u}-e^{-u}+1}du=\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-u}(1+e^{-u})u^a}{1+e^{-3u}}du\\
&=&\int_0^\infty\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^ne^{-(3n+1)u}(1+e^{-u})u^a\ du\\
&=&\int_0^\infty\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n(e^{-(3n+1)u}+e^{-(3n+2)u})u^a\ du\\
&=&\Gamma(a+1)\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^{n}\left(\frac{1}{(3n+1)^{a+1}}+\frac{1}{(3n+2)^{a+1}}\right)\\
&=&6^{-a-1}\Gamma(a+1)\left(\zeta(a+1,\frac{1}{6})+\zeta(a+1,\frac{1}{3})-\zeta(a+1,\frac{2}{3})-\zeta(a+1,\frac{5}{6})\right)
\end{eqnarray}
Hence:
\begin{eqnarray}
I'(0)&=&\frac{1}{6}\left[(\gamma-\ln 6)\left(\psi_0(\frac16)-\psi_0(\frac56)+\psi_0(\frac13)-\psi_0(\frac23)\right)\right.\\
&&\left.-\gamma_1(\frac16)-\gamma_1(\frac13)+\gamma_1(\frac23)+\gamma_1(\frac56)\right]\\
&=&\frac{1}{6}\left[-\frac{4\pi(\gamma-\ln 6)}{\sqrt 3}-\gamma_1(\frac16)-\gamma_1(\frac13)+\gamma_1(\frac23)+\gamma_1(\frac56)\right]\\
\end{eqnarray}
where $\gamma_k(x)$ is the $k$-th Stieltjes $\Gamma$ constant. Using: 
$$ \psi_0(1-z)-\psi_0(z)=\pi\cot(\pi z) $$
it is easy to get:
$$ \psi_0(\frac16)-\psi_0(\frac56)+\psi_0(\frac13)-\psi_0(\frac23)=-\frac{4\pi(\gamma-\ln 6)}{\sqrt 3}. $$
For $\gamma_1(\frac{p}{q})$, we have to use the following formula:
\begin{eqnarray}
\gamma_1(1,\frac{p}{q})-\gamma_1(1-\frac{p}{q})=-\pi(\log(2\pi q)+\gamma)\cot\frac{\pi p}{q}-2\pi\sum_{j=1}^{q-1}\ln\Gamma(\frac jq)\sin\left(\frac{2\pi jp}{q}\right)
\end{eqnarray}
from [this](http://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~marin/une_autre_crypto/Livres/Connon%20some%20series%20and%20integrals/Vol-2%28b%29.pdf). First, I have:
\begin{eqnarray}
\gamma_1(\frac{1}{3})-\gamma_1(\frac{2}{3})&=&-\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt 3}[2\gamma-\ln 3+8\ln(2\pi)-12\ln(\ln\Gamma(\frac13))],\\
\gamma_1(\frac{1}{6})-\gamma_1(\frac{5}{6})&=&-\pi\sqrt 3\left[\gamma+\ln\left(\frac{12\pi\Gamma(\frac23)\Gamma(\frac56)}{\Gamma(\frac16)\Gamma(\frac13)}\right)\right]=-\pi\sqrt 3\left[\gamma+\ln\left(\frac{4\cdot 2^{2/3}\pi^3}{3\sqrt3\Gamma^5(\frac13)}\right)\right].
\end{eqnarray}
Putting all the results together, finally we have:
\begin{eqnarray}
I'(0)&=&\frac{\pi}{12\sqrt 3}\left[\ln\frac{268435456}{531441}+32\ln\pi-48\ln\left(\Gamma(\frac13)\right)\right].
\end{eqnarray}
The numerical value is $-0.671719601885875$ which is the same as that from Mathematica command:

```
NIntegrate[Log[Log[1/x]]/(x^2 - x + 1)}, \{x, 0, 1\}]
```

Comment: In fact, you use the same ingredients as Adamchik. The missing fact is that $$\frac{\Gamma(\frac{2}{3})\Gamma(\frac{5}{6})}{\Gamma(\frac{1}{6})}=\frac{4\ 2^{2/3} \pi ^3}{3 \sqrt{3} \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^5}$$ which yields the same simplified answer. This follows from the duplication and complement formulas for $\Gamma $.

Comment: @OmranKouba, thanks.

Answer (score 7):

I'm aware that this is a really old question, but searching through most of the questions similar to the nested logarithmic integral, I haven't found this approach yet. And I feel that this approach is a lot more straightforward and doesn't require the use of any complex constants.

Let$$\mathfrak{I}=\int\limits_0^1\mathrm dx\,\frac {\log\log\left(\frac 1x\right)}{1+2x\cos a+x^2}$$denote the general form of the integral. Since$$\cos a=\frac {e^{ia}+e^{-ia}}2$$Therefore$$\begin{align*}\mathfrak{I} & =\int\limits_0^1\mathrm dx\,\frac {\log\log\left(\frac 1x\right)}{(1+xe^{ia})(1+xe^{-ia})}\\ & =\int\limits_0^1\mathrm dx\,\log\log\left(\frac 1x\right)\sum\limits_{n\geq0}\sum\limits_{m\geq0}(-1)^{n+m}x^{n+m}e^{(n-m)ia}\end{align*}$$

The double sum can be simplified by writing the sum out and expanding$$1-x(e^{ia}+e^{-ia})+x^2(e^{2ia}+1+e^{-2ia})-x^3(e^{3ia}+e^{ia}+e^{-ia}+e^{-3ia})+\cdots$$If we denote $a_n$ as the coefficient of $x^n$, then we can rewrite the coefficient as$$a_n=(-1)^n\sum\limits_{k=0}^ne^{(n-2k)ia}=(-1)^n\frac {\sin a(n+1)}{\sin a}$$
Therefore the integral becomes$$\mathfrak{I}=\frac 1{\sin a}\sum\limits_{n\geq0}(-1)^n\sin a(n+1)\int\limits_0^1\mathrm dx\, x^n\log\log\left(\frac 1x\right)$$Thie intermediate integral is much easier to consider. First set $x\mapsto-\log x$ and then make the transformation $x\mapsto x(n+1)$ to get$$\begin{align*}\int\limits_0^1\mathrm dx\,x^n\log\log\left(\frac 1x\right) & =\frac 1{n+1}\int\limits_0^{\infty}\mathrm dx\, e^{-x}\log x-\frac {\log(n+1)}{n+1}\\ & =-\frac {\gamma+\log(n+1)}{n+1}\end{align*}$$where $\gamma$ is the Euler Mascheroni constant. Splitting up the infinite sum, then$$\begin{align*}\mathfrak{I}=-\frac {\gamma a}{2\sin a}-\frac 1{\sin a}\sum\limits_{n\geq1}(-1)^{n-1}\frac {\sin an\log n}n\end{align*}$$where we have used$$\sum\limits_{n\geq1}(-1)^{n-1}\frac {\sin an}n=\frac a2$$

The remaining log - sine sum can be evaluated. There *is* a closed form in terms of the gamma function. Essentially$$\log\Gamma(x)=\left(\frac 12-x\right)(\gamma+\log 2)+(1-x)\log\pi-\frac 12\log\sin\pi x+\frac 1{\pi}\sum\limits_{n\geq1}\frac {\sin 2\pi n x\log n}n$$

The only difference between the above identity and our sum is the alternating $(-1)^n$ term. This, however, can easily be remedied by considering the expansion$$\begin{align*}\sin n(\pi-a) & =\sin\pi n\cos an-\sin an\cos\pi a\\ & =-\sin a n\cos\pi n\\ & =(-1)^{n-1}\sin an\end{align*}$$

Therefore, evaluating $x$ at $\tfrac 12-\tfrac a{2\pi}$ gives the sum to be$$\sum\limits_{n\geq1}(-1)^{n-1}\frac {\log n\sin an}n=\pi\log\Gamma\left(\frac 12-\frac a{2\pi}\right)-\frac a2(\gamma+\log 2)-\frac {\pi}2\log2\pi+\frac {\pi}2\log\cos\left(\frac a2\right)$$Hence, by properties of the natural log,$$\int\limits_0^1\mathrm dx\,\frac {\log\log\left(\frac 1x\right)}{1+2x\cos a+x^2}\color{blue}{=\frac {\pi}{\sin a}\log\left[\frac {\sqrt\pi(2\pi)^{\frac a{2\pi}}}{\Gamma\left(\frac 12-\frac a{2\pi}\right)\sqrt{\cos\left(\frac a2\right)}}\right]}$$

Now set $a=\tfrac {2\pi}3$ so that $\cos a=-\frac 12$ to get the integral in question.